# Thread-Safe Concurrent call to external command in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've been looking around on the internet trying to find a way to make concurrent calls to an external program in a thread safe manner from within my C++ program.
As far as I've understood, popen, system and fork are not thread safe.
It seems to me that there is something missing here, that I haven't been able to find so far. Is it possible that there is NO WAY to make concurrent calls from different threads to an external program? Because it seems to me that this would be one of the first examples of usage of multi-thread coding.
I am using linux (mandriva) and the external program I wish to call can be called in different shells at the same time.
I am not new to C++ but am new to multi-threading , so I would greatly appreciate any advice on the subject.
Marcelo

Comment: Thanks a lot for all answers. Indeed, popen solved the problem. A few links threw me off, but stack overflow always has the best info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think that popen, system and fork are thread-unsafe? A quote from the man page on fork:

> The child process is created with a single thread — the one that
>   called fork(). The entire virtual address space of  the  parent  is 
>   replicated  in  the child,  including  the  states  of  mutexes,
>   condition variables, and other pthreads objects; the use of
>   pthread_atfork(3) may be helpful for dealing with problems that this
>   can cause.

If you call system your thread will block until the child process exits. If you want to launch multiple external commands in parallel you can just start 10 threads which call system.

Answer (score 4):

`fork()` is thread-safe as long as you only execute async-signal-safe operations (such as `execve()` and `_exit()`) in the child process and only call `waitpid()` with an explicit pid to avoid "stealing" a zombie from another part of the program. (Note that you might be tempted to violate the former requirement, but this tends to be non-portable and fragile. The `pthread_atfork()` interface is basically broken by design.)

`popen()` is also thread-safe and fulfills the above two requirements.

`system()` may not be thread-safe, for example because it manipulates signal dispositions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, as you are on Linux, you could just use [d-bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) with a request/response protocol. That is, your threads would just send d-bus request messages without having to care about synchronization and receive responses in sync or async manner.

> D-Bus is a message bus system, a simple way for applications to talk to one another. In addition to interprocess communication, D-Bus helps coordinate process lifecycle; it makes it simple and reliable to code a "single instance" application or daemon, and to launch applications and daemons on demand when their services are needed.