# Execute shell command using threads c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, shell

Is it possible to execute a shell command by creating a thread i.e. without using popen/system or any of the fork-exec variants? Why or why not?

To provide more context, I am running a multi-threaded program, where one of the threads needs to execute a shell script. It currently does it using popen(). However, since forking in a multi-threaded program is considered bad practice, is it possible to achieve the same by spawning a thread?

Comment: I do not see any examples on the web. Could you provide an example as to how one can execute a shell command using threads in C++?

Comment: I don't understand. If I want to execute the "ls" command, I can do a system("ls") in C++. How can I use std threads to do the same thing?

Comment: To give more context, I am running a multi-threaded program, in which one thread has to execute some shell script. Currently, I do a popen() to execute that shell script. This is bad since I don't want to fork in a multi-threaded program. So, I wanted to know how I can execute that shell script without using fork i.e. can I spawn another thread and execute that shell script?

Comment: I am only trying to answer the question that was asked. If you mean something different, you will have to provide that clarification in the question itself.

Comment: @user1715122 why do you not want to use `system` ? What is missing in `std::thread task([](){system("ls");});` ? Also, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747223/thread-safe-concurrent-call-to-external-command-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Here's an useful summary on the multi-threading & fork+exec potential problems: https://web.archive.org/web/20170812180443/http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them

It seems that if you want to execute other programs and even shell scripts, you have to use fork+exec, it's unavoidable. Just be careful and prepare your threads for such a "bad" event like fork. Also you could close all unnecessary file descriptors in a special single threaded trusted execute helper being run from the main application, if that's the problem.